# Concatenating strings then printing

Tags: python, string, string-concatenation

```
print ("Tag Value " + i.tags.get('Name'))
```

gives me:

```
  File "./boto_test.py", line 19, in main
    print ("Tag Value" + i.tags.get('Name'))
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: `i.tags` doesn’t contain a `'Name'` key. What should the result be for `None`?

Comment: Look like you `i.tags.get('Name')` returns `None` here. This looks like a programmer error...

Comment: NoneType objects can not be printed. Debug your code and you will see that i.tags.get('Name') results in NoneType

Comment: @theAlse: `None` can be printed.  The problem is it can't be added to a string.

Comment: @fge There is a tag with a 'Name' key.

Comment: @BillR well, the stack trace says there isn't, or maybe there is a dedicated method in your API which converts tag elements into a usable `str` form.

Comment: The stack trace complained about types, not a variable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Or just convert whatever you `get` from `i.tags` to string:

```
print ("Tag Value " + str(i.tags.get('Name')))
```

Answer (score 1):

`i.tags` doesn’t contain a `'Name'` key. What should the result be for `None`? Just pass it as a second argument to `get`:

```
print ("Tag Value " + i.tags.get('Name', 'None'))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try converting it to the string data type by `str()` function.
Use the following code for the same line:

```
print ("Tag Value" + str(i.tags.get('Name')))
```